# How to add a pdf using MultipartEntityBuilder

Tags: android, pdf, multipartentity

I am trying to upload a pdf and image to a server. I am able to upload the image successfully. I am using the same code for pdf as it says to add only file no type :

```
  MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
 builder.addTextBody("USER_ID", Uid);
            builder.addTextBody("SERIAL_NO", Srno);
            builder.addTextBody("CUST_NO", CUST_NO);
            builder.addTextBody("SESSION_ID", Sid);
 File file = new File(filepaths.get(0));
                Log.d("file",file.getName());
//                builder.addBinaryBody("file[]", file,
//                        ContentType.create("*/*"), file.getName());
                builder.addPart("file[]",new FileBody(file));
```

for image i am getting sucess in response, in loading pdf i am getting some issue. how do i add pdf to the server using this code?

Comment: @greenapps see editted

Comment: Care to explain what "some issues" are?

Comment: Have you tried setting the minetype when uploading a PDF to see if that changes anything? The minetype should be "application/pdf". As @toKrause pointed out, we need more information about the "issues" to be able to help without guessing.

Comment: the issue is i am getting an error msg that the document uploaded is not correct, and i tried using application/pdf as the mime type